# How to redirect an error message to /dev/null?

Tags: io-redirection, dmidecode

`sudo dmidecode | grep State 2> /dev/null`

```
Boot-up State: Safe
    Power Supply State: Safe
    Thermal State: Safe
Invalid entry length (16). Fixed up to 11
```

I don't want the Invalid entry error in the output. How do I filter that?

Comment: You should put the redirect before the pipe symbol, not after.  You're redirecting `grep`'s standard error, but not `dmidecode`'s.

Comment: thanks, that was dumb but I never knew that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Wildcard commented, you've mistakenly redirected grep's stderr instead of sudo/dmidecode's. Use this instead:

```
 sudo dmidecode 2>/dev/null | grep State
```